# How to deserialize a JSON property that can be two different data types using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm using Json.NET for a project I'm working on.
From an external API, I am receiving JSON with properties that are objects, but when they are empty 'false' is passed.

For example:

```
data: {
    supplier: {
        id: 15,
        name: 'TheOne'
    }
}
```

Could also be:

```
data: {
    supplier: false
}
```

How should I define the supplier property so that the supplier will be deserialized to a Supplier object or null.

Right now I have:

```
public class Data {
   [JsonProperty("supplier")]
   public SupplierData Supplier { get; set; }
}
public class SupplierData {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But now when trying to deserialize when supplier has a value of 'false' it fails.
I would like the Supplier property to be null when the JSON value is 'false'.

I hope someone knows how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: You can create a custom JSON converter and read the JSON. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752/deserializing-polymorphic-json-classes-without-type-information-using-json-net

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This can be solved by making a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for your `SupplierData` class.  Here is what the converter might look like:

```
class SupplierDataConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(SupplierData));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            return token.ToObject<SupplierData>();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

To use it, all you would need to do is add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to the `Supplier` property in your `Data` class like this:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("supplier")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SupplierDataConverter))]
    public SupplierData Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

Below is a demonstration of the converter in action.  Note that the demo assumes you have some kind of containing object for the `data` property, since the JSON in your question can't stand on its own.  I defined a class called `RootObject` for this purpose:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

The actual demo code follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
            ""data"": 
            {
                ""supplier"": 
                {
                    ""id"": 15,
                    ""name"": ""TheOne""
                }
            }
        }";

        Console.WriteLine("--- first run ---");
        RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        DumpSupplier(obj.Data.Supplier);

        json = @"
        {
            ""data"": 
            {
                ""supplier"": false
            }
        }";

        Console.WriteLine("--- second run ---");
        obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        DumpSupplier(obj.Data.Supplier);
    }

    static void DumpSupplier(SupplierData supplier)
    {
        if (supplier != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id: " + supplier.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + supplier.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("(null)");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

And here is the output from the above:

```
--- first run ---
Id: 15
Name: TheOne

--- second run ---
(null)
```

Comment: I had a similar case where a property was either an object or an empty array. It's mostly a bad decision for an API to break like that without versioning, but this is a clean enough solution for it.

Thanks!

Comment: How can I get both? I would like both to be converted    ""supplier"": 
                {
                    ""id"": 15,
                    ""name"": ""TheOne""
                } And   json = @"
        {
            ""data"": 
            {
                ""supplier"": false
            }
        }";

Comment: @Decoder94 Perhaps you can post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and tell us what you are trying to do in more detail?  You can link back to this question/answer to provide context if needed.

Comment: @BrianRogers https://stackoverflow.com/q/62462147/5326036

Comment: I don't think this will work for array/list types. Because those are generic and used in cases where you don't need or want a conversion. How do you handle the ambiguity?

Comment: @void.pointer I don't understand what you mean.  Maybe you could post a new question about it?

Comment: You are attaching the converter to a specific property and not globally via settings, so my concern is a non-issue. Sorry for the confusion.