# Json.Net - How to deserialize only if types are matching

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a class like this:

```
public class Event
{
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status"]
            public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

I am receiving JSON that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 4,
        "status": "started"
    },
    {
        "_id": 117841261,
        "status": {
            "_statusid": 1,
            "date": "01.01.2015"
        }
    }
]
```

Please be aware: in the first object, the *status* field is a *string*. In the second object, it's an *object*. In my object it's a *string* property. I want to parse it whenever the status field is a string. I'm okay with skipping it when it's an object like in the second object.

I have tried changing the `defaultValueHanding` options in the `JsonProperty` attribute, but it didn't help. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: In the second object, status is an object, not an array.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the marked question because it is not asking about schema validation.  However, I would argue it IS a duplicate of [How to deserialize a JSON property that can be two different data types using Json.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20432166/10263)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem chaging property type to dynamic. So it's deserializing everytime with no problem and i am using it only when i need it.

Now my model looks like this:

```
public class Event
{
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status"]
            public dynamic Status { get; set; }
}
```

As Brian Rogers pointed out, custom converter can be found here:

[How to deserialize a JSON property that can be two different data types using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432166/how-to-deserialize-a-json-property-that-can-be-two-different-data-types-using-js)