# C# class name based on variable

Tags: c#

In my app, I've got responses from a server. These responses can be :

```
{
    "cmd":"read_ack",
    "model":"sensor_ht",
    "sid":"158d0001a2ddac",
    "short_id":36192,
    "data":"{\"voltage\":3005,\"temperature\":\"2741\",\"humidity\":\"5828\"}"
}
```

Or it can be :

```
{  
    "cmd":"read_ack",
    "model":"magnet",
    "sid":"158d000159febe",
    "short_id":40805,
    "data":"{\"voltage\":3045,\"status\":\"open\"}"
}
```

Can I use something like "dynamic" class ?

My class look like this :

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string cmd { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string sid { get; set; }
        public int short_id { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }
```

And my data class looks like :

```
    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int voltage { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string status { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string temperature { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string humidity { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string no_close { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string no_motion { get; set; }
    }
```

Is it possible to have different classes for each type of response I get ? Is it possible to change the data type in RootObject class dynamically ?

Thank a lot

Comment: Try inheritance (I think that's what you want). If all your classes need the stuff in RootObject then get them to inherit from it. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432166/how-to-deserialize-a-json-property-that-can-be-two-different-data-types-using-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a custom converter as explained in [How to deserialize a JSON property that can be two different data types using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432166/how-to-deserialize-a-json-property-that-can-be-two-different-data-types-using-js), and inheritance to change the data type.

You could approach it with an empty base class that more derived types implement:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string cmd { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string sid { get; set; }
    public int short_id { get; set; }
    public SensorData data { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SensorData
{       
}

public class MagnetData : SensorData
{
    public int Voltage { get; set; }
}

public class SomeOtherSensorData : SensorData
{
    public bool AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your converter, either deserialize into a `MagnetData` or `SomeOtherSensorData` or whatever other classes you want.

That is, granted that you actually want to create a class per type of data. There are pros and cons to that.

Alternatively, just deserialize your `data` into a `Dictionary<string, object>`, where you pull out the relevant fields by their (string) name.

Comment: Thank it works. However my main program use the type inside a class to build documentation for the function. So it's empty because SensorData is empty. But I think there is no solution to this minor problem.