# Deserialize multiple JSON records in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have the following string of Json records:

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "PK":"1_1_8",
         "ID":"8",
         "DeviceID":"1",
         "RootID":"1",
         "CustName":"test1",
         "CustSurname":"test2",
         "Address":"Nisou 1",
         "City":"",
         "ZipCode":"",
         "PhoneNumber":"45646",
         "HomePhoneNumber":"",
         "Email":"",
         "Notes":"",
         "Owner":"1",
         "LanguageID":"1",
         "LanguagePK":"",
         "DeletedFlag":"false",
         "created":"2017-10-25 10:15:00",
         "modified":"2017-10-25 09:35:43"
      },
      {
         "PK":"1_1_33",
         "ID":"33",
         "DeviceID":"1",
         "RootID":"1",
         "CustName":"",
         "CustSurname":"",
         "Address":"",
         "City":"",
         "ZipCode":"",
         "PhoneNumber":"",
         "HomePhoneNumber":"",
         "Email":"",
         "Notes":"",
         "Owner":null,
         "LanguageID":"0",
         "LanguagePK":"",
         "DeletedFlag":"true",
         "created":"2017-10-25 10:13:54",
         "modified":"2017-10-25 10:13:54"
      },
      {
         "PK":"1_1_16",
         "ID":"16",
         "DeviceID":"1",
         "RootID":"1",
         "CustName":"Theodosis",
         "CustSurname":"",
         "Address":"Dali",
         "City":"Nicosia",
         "ZipCode":"2540",
         "PhoneNumber":"45645",
         "HomePhoneNumber":"99123456",
         "Email":"theodosis@gmail.com",
         "Notes":"",
         "Owner":"",
         "LanguageID":"1",
         "LanguagePK":"",
         "DeletedFlag":"false",
         "created":"2017-10-25 09:36:22",
         "modified":"2017-10-25 09:36:22"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am using Xamarin PCL in C# trying to parse this string into a list of objects.

I have a `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string PK { get; set; }
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string RootID{ get; set; }

    public string CustName { get; set; }
    public string CustSurname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string HomePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public bool Owner { get; set; }

    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
    public string LanguagePK { get; set; }

    public bool DeletedFlag { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public DateTime modified { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried out having a container class with a list of `Customer` objects.

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public List<Customer> customers { get; set; }
}
```

I have seen quite a few of examples online on how to parse this into a list or any workable type but nothing seems to be working for me.

I have tried the following (JsonResults holds the string of Json records):

```
var observation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataContainer>(JsonResults);
```

From other posts, I am not able to access `JavaScriptSerializer` class from my code, perhaps because of the Xamarin PCL Framework I am using.

Any ideas would be very welcome, as I said I do not mind the format I parse the string into, as long as it's workable.

Thank you.

Comment: Yous Json starts with an object containing a property `records`. Have you tried renaming (or annotating) `customers` to `records`?

Comment: `JavaScriptSerializer` is obsolete, Everyone uses Json.NET. If you have a problem, it doesn't mean that Json.NET is broken, it means the code is wrong. Post the *error message*. Most likely it complains that your string doesn't match your class (it doesn't). Json has a `records` property whil your class has a `customers` property

Comment: if you observe that your json is having key as "records" but in your DataContainer you have property as customers

Comment: Also you need a JsonConverter for `Owner` or change it to a `int?`.

Comment: Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/d8MJWT

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string you provided is a JSON object, which contains a single property called `records`. `records` property is a `List<Customer>`. You can not deserialize the given string directly into `DataContainer` class that you provided because the property names do not match.

In the Class that your provided it is called `customers`

```
public class DataContainer {
    public List<Customer> customers { get; set; } //records
}
```

Or please have a look at the attribute for a bit of advanced mapping

```
[JsonProperty]
```

JSON you provided is of the form:

```
{"records":[{Customer},{Customer},{Customer}]}
```

But `Owner` property is `"1"`, `null` or `""`. Therefore I would suggest redefining Owner as `int?` (nullable)

Comment: It's *NOT* a list of objects. It's *one* object that contains a property named `records`, which has a list of other objects

Comment: The original answer was wrong. There's no list of objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Yeah i read the comments and thanked you for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make the following changes to your code to make this work.

First and most importantly, you don't have a property `customers`, you have `records`, so either rename it

```
public class DataContainer {
    public List<Customer> records { get; set; }
}
```

or add a `JsonProperty` attribute

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "records")]
```

Secondly, your `Owner` is a `bool` in C# and a nullable `int` (`int?`) in Json. So either change it in your C# class

```
public int?  Owner { get; set; }
```

or write a converter to do that ([e.g. like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895462/3214843))

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(NullableIntToBooleanConverter))]
public bool Owner { get; set; }
```

[Here is a working .NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/d8MJWT)

Comment: @CodeCaster Fair enough - find a duplicate and I'll chip in a close-vote.

Answer (score -2):

Your string shows *one* object with a property named `records` that contains a list of other objects. Your code is trying to deserialize this into an object that doesn't have such a property.

Furthermore, the string contains objects with a property `Owner` that may be missing or have a numeric value. It's definitely not a bool.

You'll have to change Owner to :

```
public int?  Owner { get; set; }
```

To deserialize the string, you need an object with a `records` property:

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public Customer[] records { get; set; }
}

var data=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataContainer>(json);
Debug.Assert(data.records.Length == 3);
```