# How to read with interfaces in the model?

Tags: c#, json.net

I would like to know how to read the JSON with a dynamic layout into my object that has an interface `IPeople`. When I try I get an error:

> 'Could not create an instance of type 'xxxx'. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

I have spent 2 days searching through Google and I tried using converters and it only works for one object at a time So I would have to choose between a Staff converter and a spectator converter.

How can I get both objects to load using the interface `IPeople` that loads to the `Staff` object if the staff data is detected and `Spectator` object if the spectator data is detected (possibly more object types all have unique properties).

```
{
    "appCore": 
    {
        "Crowd": 
        [
            {
                "Name": "Name1",
                "Staff":
                {  
                    "PopupText":
                    [
                        {   "DisplayName":"No Popup Text","PopupValue":"", "IsSeperator":false},
                        {   "DisplayName":"--------------","PopupValue":"", "IsSeperator":true},
                        {   "DisplayName":"HT","PopupValue":"HT", "IsSeperator":false}
                    ]

                },
                "Spectator":
                {  
                    "PopupText2":
                    [
                        {   "DisplayName":"No Popup Text","PopupValue":"", "Cheese":"hiih"},
                        {   "DisplayName":"--------------","PopupValue":"",  "Cheese":"hiih"},
                        {   "DisplayName":"Half-Time","PopupValue":"Half-Time",  "Cheese":"hiih"}
                    ]
                }          
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

C#  Models:

```
public class Crowd : ICrowd
{
    public IPeople People { get; set; }
}


public class Staff :  IPeople
{
    IList<PopupTextData> PopupText { get; set; }
}

public class Spectator : IPeople
{
    IList<PopupTextData2> PopupText2 { get; set; }
}

public class PopupTextData
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string PopupValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsSeperator { get; set; }
}

public class PopupTextData2
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string PopupValue { get; set; }
    public string Cheese { get; set; }
}
```

Code used to read the data:

```
settings.ForEach(type =>
{
    builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MCoreReader>().LoadSection(type))
        .As(type.GetInterfaces())
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .InstancePerRequest()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
});

public static object LoadSection(Type type, string _configurationFilePath, string _sectionNameSuffix)
{
    if (!File.Exists(_configurationFilePath))
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    var jsonFile = File.ReadAllText(_configurationFilePath);
    var section = ToCamelCase(type.Name.Replace(_sectionNameSuffix, string.Empty));
    var settingsData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonFile, JsonSerializerSettings);
    var settingsSection = settingsData[section];
    return settingsSection == null
        ? Activator.CreateInstance(type)
        : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settingsSection), type, JsonSerializerSettings);
}

private class SettingsReaderContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Select(p => CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization))
            .Union(type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Select(f => CreateProperty(f, memberSerialization)))
            .ToList();
        props.ForEach(p =>
        {
            p.Writable = true;
            p.Readable = true;
        });

        return props;
    }
}

private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    ContractResolver = new SettingsReaderContractResolver(),
};
```

Comment: If you're creating this Json then reading it back in, have you looked at using [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm)?

Comment: I am creating it manually(hand-typed) as I go Along, are you saying that if I create the model first then Serialize it with the same settings it will work? @stuartd I tried `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto` and `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All`(reading only)

Comment: If you include the type information when you create the Json, then when you read it back in Json.Net can assign the correct type (including subclass).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you control the Json, here's a working example: I've changed the class structure a bit.

It uses [TypeNameHandling.All](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) which writes the type information into the Json - as `$type` -, so when it's deserialized (using the same setting), it can restore the type.

```
void Main() {
    var crowd = new Crowd {
        People = new List<IPeople> {
            new Staff {
                PopupText = new List<PopupTextData> {
                new PopupTextData { DisplayName = "Staff"}
            }},
            new Spectator {
                PopupText = new List<PopupTextData> {
                new PopupTextData { DisplayName = "Spectator"}
            }},
        }
    };

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(crowd, settings);

    var newCrowd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ICrowd>(json, settings);
    Console.WriteLine(newCrowd.People.Count); // outputs '2'


}

public interface ICrowd {
    IList<IPeople> People { get; set; }
}

public interface IPeople {
    IList<PopupTextData> PopupText { get; set; }
}

public class Crowd : ICrowd {
    public IList<IPeople> People { get; set; }
}

public class Staff : IPeople {
    public IList<PopupTextData> PopupText { get; set; }
}

public class Spectator : IPeople {
    public IList<PopupTextData> PopupText { get; set; }
}

public class PopupTextData {
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string PopupValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsSeperator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the cheese.

Comment: @BrianRogers so I did :) But then again, Staff and Spectator had different implementations of IPeople, so something had to change.

Comment: @stuartd Nothing had to change in terms of structuring, it might be breaking a rule but that's how I need it with different implementations of the same interface. Thanks, to you I have it working now using  `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto`   I realised it adds a decoration `$type` which is perfect for what I need it for. if you somehow change your answer to something along the lines of if you are creating the json your self use `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling` and it will add `$Type`. I will accept it