# C# Type casting Object Property With different Value

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to send a Array Of Object which is looks like below to Asp.Net  API Contoller (Post Method and .Net Framework 4.5)

```
    var itemChanges = [];
   
   itemChanges.push({
        name: "Item1",
        desc: "percentage",
        value: 1
    });

    itemChanges.push({
        name: "Item2",
        desc: "detail",
        value: "sample_test"
    });

    itemChanges.push({
        name: "Item3",
        desc: "field",
        value: {
            name: "foo",                
            value: "test"
        }
    });
```

I send above array Object Json to API Contoller. But third item not parsed correctly. Adivce how can I receive it in Object Format. The 'value' property may have different types of Data. But it should be received

And I need to receive it in C# side.

For real time case check [PayPal Update Subscription API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_patch) Sample

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432166/how-to-deserialize-a-json-property-that-can-be-two-different-data-types-using-js

Answer (score 0):

Use type `object` for property `value`, then you can type-check on the C# server-side using pattern matching (`x is Type` or `x as Type`) to handle specific `Value` types.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```